# How to draw a multi-colored dashed line (alternating colors for visual effect)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if it is possible to create a multicolored dashed line in ggplot.
Basically I have a plot displaying savings based on two packages.

A orange line with savings based on package A
A green line with savings based on package B

I also have a third line and I would like that one to be dashed alterenating between orange and green. Is that something that somebody has been able to do?

Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

S <- seq(0, 5, by = 0.05)

a <- S ^ 2
b <- S
a_b = a + b #This data should have the dashed multicolor line, since it is the sum of the other two lines.

S <- data.frame(S)
temp <- cbind(S, a, b, a_b)
temp <- gather(temp, variable, value, -S)
desiredOrder <- c("a", "b", "a_b")
temp$variable <- factor(temp$variable, levels = desiredOrder)
temp <- temp[order(temp$variable),]

p <- ggplot(temp, aes(x = S, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("orange", "green", "#0085bd"),
                     breaks = c("a", "b", "a_b"))
p
```

I basically want to have a multicolored (dashed or dotted) line for "c"

[image]

Comment: Yeah, probably. That's my answer to most "is it possible to do xyz in R" questions. To get more specific than that, we'd need a clear example of what you're doing and how you're trying to do it

Comment: Now that there's an example of what you're trying to do, I'm voting to reopen this. Just FYI, to keep the question minimal and focused on the problem at hand, you could skip the first 10 lines of code that create the dataset by just giving us a sample of it with `dput`

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498588/ggplot-line-plot-different-colors-for-sections

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644237/alternating-color-of-individual-dashes-in-a-geom-line

Answer (score 2):

This is, to my best knowledge, currently only possible via creation of new segments for each alternate color. This is fiddly.

Below I've tried a largely programmatic approach in which you can define the size of the repeating segment (based on your x unit). The positioning of y values is slightly convoluted and it will also result in slightly irregular segment lengths when dealing with different slopes. I also haven't tested it on many data, either. But I guess it's a good start :)

For the legend, I'm taking the same approach, by creating a fake legend and stitching it onto the other plot. The challenges here include:

1. positioning of legend elements relative to the plot
2. relative distance between the legend elements

**update**
For a much neater way [to create those segments and a Stat implementation see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644237/alternating-color-of-individual-dashes-in-a-geom-line/70756000#70756000)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

S <- seq(0, 5, by = 0.05)
a <- S^2
b <- S
a_b <- a + b

df <- data.frame(x = S, a, b, a_b) %>%
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

## a function to create modifiable cuts in order to get segments.
## this looks convoluted - and it is! there are a few if/else statements.
## Why? The assigment of new y to x values depends on how many original values
## you have.
## There might be more direct ways to get there
alt_colors <- function(df, x, y, seg_length, my_cols) {
  x <- df[[x]]
  y <- df[[y]]
  ## create new x for each tiny segment
  length_seg <- seg_length / length(my_cols)
  new_x <- seq(min(x, na.rm = TRUE), x[length(x)], length_seg)
  ## now we need to interpolate y values for each new x
  ## This is different depending on how many x and new x you have
  if (length(new_x) < length(x)) {
    ind_int <- findInterval(new_x, x)
    new_y <- sapply(seq_along(ind_int), function(i) {
      if (y[ind_int[i]] == y[ind_int[length(ind_int)]]) {
        y[ind_int[i]]
      } else {
        seq_y <- seq(y[ind_int[i]], y[ind_int[i] + 1], length.out = length(my_cols))
        head(seq_y, -1)
      }
    })
  } else {
    ind_int <- findInterval(new_x, x)
    rle_int <- rle(ind_int)
    new_y <- sapply(rle_int$values, function(i) {
      if (y[i] == y[max(rle_int$values)]) {
        y[i]
      } else {
        seq_y <- seq(y[i], y[i + 1], length.out = rle_int$lengths[i] + 1)
        head(seq_y, -1)
      }
    })
  }
  ## THis is also a bit painful and might cause other bugs that I haven't
  ## discovered yet.
  if (length(unlist(new_y)) < length(new_x)) {
    newdat <- data.frame(
      x = new_x,
      y = rep_len(unlist(new_y), length.out = length(new_x))
    )
  } else {
    newdat <- data.frame(x = new_x, y = unlist(new_y))
  }
  newdat <- newdat %>%
    mutate(xend = lead(x), yend = lead(y)) %>%
    drop_na(xend)
  newdat$color <- my_cols
  newdat
}

## the below is just a demonstration of how the function would work
## using different segment widths
df_alt1 <-
  df %>%
  filter(variable == "a_b") %>%
  alt_colors("x", "value", 1, c("orange", "green"))

df_alt.5 <-
  df %>%
  filter(variable == "a_b") %>%
  alt_colors("x", "value", .5, c("orange", "green"))

df_ab <-
  df %>%
  filter(variable != "a_b") %>%
  # for the identity mapping
  mutate(color = ifelse(variable == "a", "green", "orange"))

## create data frame for the legend, also using the alt_colors function as per above
## the amount of x is a bit of trial and error, this is just a quick hack
## this is a trick to center the legend more or less relative to the main plot
y_leg <- ceiling(mean(range(df$value, na.rm = TRUE)))
dist_y <- 2

df_legend <-
  data.frame(
    variable = rep(unique(df$variable), each = 2),
    x = 1:2,
    y = rep(seq(y_leg - dist_y, y_leg + dist_y, by = dist_y), each = 2)
  )

df_leg_onecol <-
  df_legend %>%
  filter(variable != "a_b") %>%
  mutate(color = ifelse(variable == "a", "green", "orange"))

df_leg_alt <-
  df_legend %>%
  filter(variable == "a_b") %>%
  alt_colors("x", "y", .5, c("orange", "green"))

## I am mapping the colors globally using identity mapping (see scale_identity).
p1 <-
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x, value, colour = color)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_line(data = df_ab, size = 1) +
  geom_segment(data = df_alt1, aes(y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), size = 1) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  ggtitle("alternating every 1 unit")

p.5 <-
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x, value, colour = color)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_line(data = df_ab, size = 1) +
  geom_segment(data = df_alt.5, aes(y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), size = 1) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  ggtitle("alternating every .5 unit")

p_leg <-
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y, colour = color)) +
  theme_void() +
  geom_line(data = df_leg_onecol, size = 1) +
  geom_segment(data = df_leg_alt, aes(xend = xend, yend = yend), size = 1) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  annotate(
    geom = "text", y = unique(df_legend$y), label = unique(df_legend$variable),
    x = max(df_legend$x + 1), hjust = 0
  )

## set y limits to the range of the main plot
## in order to make the labels visible you need to adjust the plot margin and
## turn clipping off
p1 + p.5 +
  (p_leg + coord_cartesian(ylim = range(df$value), clip = "off") +
    theme(plot.margin = margin(r = 20, unit = "pt"))) +
  plot_layout(widths = c(1, 1, .2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. Would I still be able to include a legend as in the original example? But this was already very helpful. And yeah I really shouldn't name it "c" considering c() ....

Comment: Okay I will do that thank you!

Comment: Sadly haven't been able to solve this problem myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 2):

(Copied this over from [Alternating color of individual dashes in a geom_line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644237/alternating-color-of-individual-dashes-in-a-geom-line))
Here's a ggplot hack that is simple, **but works for two colors only**. It results in two lines being overlayed, one a solid line, the other a dashed line.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Create df
x_value <- 1:10
group1 <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
group2 <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
dat <- data.frame(x_value, group1, group2) %>%
  mutate(group2_2 = group2) %>% # Duplicate the column that you want to be alternating colors
  melt(id.vars = "x_value", variable.name = "group", value.name ="y_value") # Long format

# Put in your selected order
dat$group <- factor(dat$group, levels=c("group1", "group2", "group2_2"))

# Plot
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x_value, y=y_value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=group, linetype=group), size=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "red", "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "dashed"))
```

Unfortunately the legend still needs to be edited by hand. [Here's the example plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx9Fx.png)